# append string to list/string returns 'None' or 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'' in python

Tags: python, string, list, attributeerror

I'm trying to add 1 word/string to the back of the sentence 'Afterall , what affects one family '.

Using the append method, it either returns 'None' if I append directly to the list or it will return an error 'AttributeError' if I append to the string. May I know how do I add the word/string to the back of the sentence?

```
S1 = 'Afterall , what affects one family '
Insert_String = 'member'
S1_List = ['Afterall', ',', 'what', 'affects', 'one', 'family']
print(type(S1_List))
print(type(Insert_String))
print(type(S1))

print(S1_List)
print(Insert_String)
print(S1)

print(S1_List.append(Insert_String))
print(S1.append(Insert_String))




Output

<type 'list'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
['Afterall', ',', 'what', 'affects', 'one', 'family']
member
Afterall , what affects one family 
None
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-2fdb520ebc6d> in <module>()
     11 
     12 print(S1_List.append(Insert_String))
---> 13 print(S1.append(Insert_String))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here is that, in Python, a "list" is mutable and a "string" is not -- it cannot be changed.  The "list.append" operation modifies the list, but returns nothing.  So, try:

```
S1_List.append(Insert_String)
print(S1_List)
print(S1 + Insert_String)
```

Answer (score 1):

The string data type is immutable and does not have an `append()` method. You could try to perform string concatenation:

```py
old_string = old_string + new_string
```

Comment: You could also use the augmented assignment operator: `old_string += new_string`